# How to store "DateTime.now" as the current DateTime object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, datetime

My environment is:

- Ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-darwin18]
- Rails 6.0.2.1
- MacOS X Mojave
- psql
- Puma Version 4.3.3 (Ruby 2.6.3-p62)

For some reason Rails is saving `DateTime.now` in my database as 7 hours in the future:

```
2.6.3 :002 > DateTime.now
 => Sun, 12 Apr 2020 20:52:00 -0700
2.6.3 :003 > v.last_prompting = DateTime.now
 => Sun, 12 Apr 2020 20:52:05 -0700
2.6.3 :004 > v.save
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Volunteer Update (0.3ms)  UPDATE "volunteers" SET "updated_at" = ?, "last_prompting" = ? WHERE "volunteers"."id" = ?  [["updated_at", "2020-04-13 03:52:10.964288"], ["last_prompting", "2020-04-13 03:52:05.779767"], ["id", 1]]
   (1.1ms)  commit transaction
 => true
2.6.3 :005 > v.last_prompting
 => Sun, 12 Apr 2020 20:52:05 PDT -07:00
```

Look at `last_prompting` and `updated_at` - both are on April 13, and today is April 12.

But when I examine the time in the console, it does the right thing:

```
2.6.3 :005 > v.last_prompting
 => Sun, 12 Apr 2020 20:52:05 PDT -07:00
2.6.3 :006 > v.last_prompting.future?
 => false
2.6.3 :007 > v.last_prompting.past?
 => true
```

I'm trying to write a method to express how long ago the `last_prompting` was:

```
def prompting_age
    return "never" if self.last_prompting == nil

    if self.last_prompting.between?(Time.now - 720.minutes, Time.now - 10.years)
      ">12 hrs"
    elsif self.last_prompting.between?(Time.now - 240.minutes, Time.now - 719.minutes)
      ">4 hrs"
    elsif self.last_prompting.between?(Time.now - 61.minutes, Time.now - 239.minutes)
      ">1 hr"
    elsif self.last_prompting.between?(Time.now, Time.now - 60.minutes)
      "<1 hr"
    else
      "weird"
    end
end
```

Every time I test this method, it returns "weird". I think this is because Rails is giving the future date, but it doesn't do this in the console just when I run the application through Puma.

Comment: We can't tell for sure what the problem is because you didn't tell us anything about your DB schema but it smells like a timezone mismatch. Your console knows what time zone your computer is in, but the database has no clue and is probably using UTC. That can result in such a mismatch. You can tell the database what timezone to use, or, probably smarter, convert your DateTime and Time values to UTC prior to storing them. Also, are you using `psql` or PostgreSQL? `psql` is the CLI client, PostgreSQL is the DBM; They're different and not to be confused.

Comment: `Time.zone.now.in_time_zone('Etc/UTC')` would solve it.

Comment: I strongly recommend reading https://thoughtbot.com/blog/its-about-time-zones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [`between?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Comparable.html#method-i-between-3F) the `min` argument has to come first before the `max`. You basically just need to switch the attribute order.

A version using common Ruby idiom would look like this:

```
def prompting_age
  return "never" unless last_prompting

  if last_prompting.between?(10.years.ago, 12.hours.ago)
    ">12 hrs"
  elsif last_prompting.between?(12.hours.ago, 4.hours.ago)
    ">4 hrs"
  elsif last_prompting.between?(239.minutes.ago, 61.minutes.ago)
    ">1 hr"
  elsif last_prompting.between?(60.minutes.ago, Time.current)
    "<1 hr"
  else
    "weird"
  end
end
```

Changes:

- No need for `self` in your code.
- No explicit check against `== nil` because `nil` is already falsely in Ruby
- Change `Time.now - 720.minutes` to `720.minutes.ago` which is easier to read, shorter and respects time zone information. And use `Time.current` instead of `Time.now` to respect time zone information too.

Furthermore, you are missing some points in time in your comparison, for example, one condition is up to `60.minutes` but the next starts at `61.minutes.ago`. That means you will miss records, for example, prompted 60 minutes and 10 seconds ago.

To fix the I would rewrite the code to something like this:

```
def prompting_age
  return "never" unless last_prompting

  if last_prompting.before?(12.hours.ago)
    ">12 hrs"
  elsif last_prompting.before?(4.hours.ago)
    ">4 hrs"
  elsif last_prompting.before?(60.minutes.ago)
    ">1 hr"
  elsif last_prompting.before?(Time.current)
    "<1 hr"
  else
    "weird"
  end
end
```

Note that the last version has a slightly changed behavior. It does not return "weird" for records prompted more than 10 years ago and it is one second off from you version. Both is probably okay...